# AX Lookup problem - errorCode:1100 error:Permission denied portName:'com.apple.iphone.axserver' PID

Tags: ios, objective-c, sfsafariviewcontroller

xCode 11.6, iOS 11.4, Objective C app.  Launching a SFSafariViewController from a UIViewController.  My UIViewController is the delegate of the SFSafariViewController.

```
NSString *sURL = [dctData objectForKey:@"URL"];
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:sURL];
safari = [[SFSafariViewController alloc] initWithURL:URL];
[_safari setDelegate: self];

[self presentViewController:_safari animated:YES completion:nil];
```

The delegate method safariViewControllerDidFinish works.

I receive the following error in the debug window:

[AXRuntimeCommon] AX Lookup problem - errorCode:1100 error:Permission denied portName:'com.apple.iphone.axserver' PID:284 (
0   AXRuntime                           0x000000019f8e47b0 1BF005F5-4F9C-3C5B-9FDA-419692AB5039 + 264112
1   AXRuntime                           0x000000019f8aa87c _AXGetPortFromCache + 544
2   AXRuntime                           0x000000019f8abca0 AXUIElementPerformFencedActionWithValue + 388
3   UIKit                               0x00000001cbb503cc 315F0544-BEE8-3A6B-999F-CF5CD922DDE9 + 783308
4   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000101d82338 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
5   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000101d83730 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
6   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000101d85e88 _dispatch_queue_override_invoke + 872
7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000101d94d74 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 376
8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000101d95698 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 152
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000195010b38 _pthread_wqthread + 212
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000195013740 start_wqthread + 8

The app does not crash.

I've researched this and none of the posts lead me to a resolution.

Any ideas?

Comment: I am having a very similar if not the exact same error when trying to present a UIImagePickerController. Were you able to find a solution to this problem?

Comment: I'm getting this error when I use UICloudSharingController. It seems this error occurs when a specifically purposed UIViewController is used. There is a post about this error in Apple Developer Forums that the statement to present the specific subclass of UIViewController be run in DispatchQueue.main.async.

Answer (score 0):

Check if there are 2 app builds on the device or in the simulator using the same app group container. And then be sure that you open the correct App